# ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, listener, tnsnames

I created container `orcl2` database with pluggable database `pdborcl2`. When I try to connect

```
SQL> connect system@pdborcl2
```

I get this error:

> ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

My `tnsnames.ora` look as follows:

```
ORCL2 =  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl2.localhost))) 
PDBORCL2 = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl2.localhost)))
```

I can normally connect to `orcl2` with:

```
SQL> connect system@orcl2
```

Comment: btw. I can normally connect [SQL> connect system@orcl2] and it works

Comment: When you set your `ORACLE_SID` to `pdborcl2` can you connect to the instance? If so what does the command `show parameter service` show? What does the (shell) command `lsnrctl status`give?

Comment: When I switch `ORACLE_SID` to `pdborcl2` i do not have sqlplus. "`bash: sqlplus: command not found...`"

Comment: You used `oraenv` to switch? If so then your `oratab` file is missing  `pdborcl2`. Try to set the `ORACLE_SID` from the command line and execute `sqlplus` right after.

Comment: `show parameter service` showed NAME: `service_name` TYPE: `string` VALUE: `orcl2.localdomain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `CONNECT DATA` instead of `CONNECT_DATA` (space instead of underscore). Fix that, and try again.

Comment: Also I was missing some information in listener.ora file. I used `netca` command to configure listener. Thank you!